# Kylin Ubuntu in Tianhe 2

Tags: server, kylin

I have heard that the world's fastest supercomputer, [Tianhe 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianhe-2) , runs Ubuntu Kylin. Is it true ? What type of Operating System is Ubuntu Kylin?

Answer (score 16):

#### Tianhe - 2  and Its Operating System

Tianhe - 2 (天河二号) uses `Kylin OS` as operating system, according to [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianhe-2), which cites [Jack Dongarra's report for University of Tennessee](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/tianhe-2-dongarra-report.pdf)

[image: Wikipedia Screenshot]

Quote from the original article by Dongarra:

> The   Software    Stack The Tianhe-2 is using Kylin Linux as the operating system. Kylin is an operating system developed by the National University for Defense Technology, and successfully approved by China’s 863 Hi-tech Research and Development Program office in 2006. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylin_(operating_system) for addition details . . .This is the same OS used in the Tianhe-1A.

Since I can speak Chinese, I have also consulted one of the articles on the [National Supercomputer Center in Guangzhou website](http://www.nscc-gz.cn/newsdetail.html?5119):

[image]
Translation of the passage:

> Cloud services contain two levels: first, Kylin OS ; second Kylin cloud platform. The Kylin OS is a 64-bit OS that provides low level KVM 
>   virtualization support . . . (Translation is mine)

---

#### Kylin OS (麒麟) 　vs Ubuntu Kylin　（优麒麟）

[Kylin Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylin_(operating_system)) is a separate project, which originally was based on FreeBSD, so it is different from [Ubuntu Kylin](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin). It should be noted that Ubuntu Kylin in and of itself has Ubuntu as base and Unity desktop , but distinguishes itself in providing apps that are specifically tailored for mainland Chinese users. Just as any other Ubuntu flavor, it can serve as server for computational or other purposes.

#### Side notes

- [Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/tianhe-2-most-powerful-supercomputer-in-the-world-runs-ubuntu-487271.shtml) incorrectly attributes Ubuntu Kylin to be running on Tianhe.

Comment: Mention the incorrect Softpedia article http://news.softpedia.com/news/tianhe-2-most-powerful-supercomputer-in-the-world-runs-ubuntu-487271.shtml